# Renew ClickOnce certificate failed even it is targeting the .NET 4.0 Framework

Tags: visual-studio-2010, certificate, clickonce

It is stated clearly on microsoft article that "If you are using Visual Studio 2010 and targeting .NET 4.0, you should be okay in all cases."
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff369721.aspx

I have a ClickOnce App published to public for 1 year. It was published a dozen of times by  Visual Studio 2010 and targeting the .NET 4.0 Framework, automatically upgraded. Everything works fine till the certificate is getting expired soon (in 1 week). I just brought a new one from the same vendor, and tried to publish my App with the new certificate using Visual Studio 2010 and targeting the .NET 4.0 Framework. In another word, nothing got changed except with a new certificate.

Now if I start my installed App to trigger the automatic upgrade, I got the error windows poped up "Application cannot be started. Contact the application vendor". 
Debug message:
....
    * Activation of C:\Users\xxxxx| resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + The deployment identity does not match the subscription.

The funny thing is I got this error when I tried to publish the App to my production website server. However it works all fine if I tried exactly the same on my development website server.

Steps:

1. Publish App version 2.10 signed with old certificate to development server. Install the App to a local machine
2. Publish App version 2.10 signed with new certificate to development server which overwrite the existing one. Start the App, trigger the automatic upgrade. Works fine!

Steps:

1. Publish App version 2.10 signed with old certificate to production server. Install the App to a local machine
2. Publish App version 2.10 signed with new certificate to production server which overwrite the existing one. Start the App, error windows popped up. (uninstall/install, then works)
3. Install the App signed with new certificate to a clean machine, works fine.

My development server and production server are exactly the same configuration: Windows server 2012, .Net Framework 4.5. They are hosted on different physical servers and with different IP addresses.

The App has been installed to thousands of machines, cannot afford to ask everyone to uninstall/install it.

Answer (score 4):

It's solved.

The App installer folder on production server was http://www.example.com all the time.
However, it was redirected to http://example.com on web server for the past year. It has never been a problem when I published the App with old cert. So now I am publishing a the App with new cert to  www.example.com, and it was automatically redirected to example.com by web server, though they are principally the same ip address.

That's probably why the Clickonce failed because it must consider www.example.com and example.com as different folder though it's always www.example.com in VS solution.
I have to disable the www redirect to renew the cert.